# Why did my key got stored in home instead of .ssh?

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I created an RSA key pair, and during the process, I got the message:

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/pedro/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

So I supposed that after giving it a name, it would store the key in the `.ssh` folder. However, the only thing inside the `.ssh` folder is the `known_hosts` and my key got stored in `home`. Did I misunderstand how this process works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example - `/home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa` - provides the default key name `id_rsa` and the default path `/home/<user>/.ssh/` where it will be stored. So analogically you should provide a *path* and a *filename*. In case you don't provide a *path* the key will be generated within the current directory.